# The amount of memory a Python set spends increases in steps

Tags: python, numpy

I do an experiment about how much memory each of Python array types spends, which is `list`, `tuple`, `set`, `dict`, `np.array`. Then i got the following result.

[image: The amount of memory Python array types spend]

(x axis is the length of array, y axis is the memory size.)

I found that the amount of memory a Python `set` spends increases in steps(also `dict`), while those of others increase linearly as i expected. I wonder what makes them different.

I used following `get_size()` function. ([reference](https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object))

```
def get_size(obj, seen = None):
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum([get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()])
        size += sum([get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()])
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in obj])
    return size
```

And i measured the memory from length 0 to 10,000 in 100 intervals.

my code : https://repl.it/repls/WanEsteemedLines

Comment: pre-allocation probably, like most pyhton collections.

Comment: For future reference, you may want to show the benchmark *code* that you used.

Comment: Yes, show the benchmarking code please, this will allow others to try to reproduce what you've shown and moreover ensure that this behaviour isn't an artefact of your code setup

Comment: set and dict are both hash-based data structure. Presumably for load-balancing they have to allocate extra "buckets" (which then requires extra memory) to ensure they remain efficient. I think that is what causes the distinctive "steps" compared to the other data structures being compared.

Comment: that's also the case for `list` (we should see some small steps at least)

Comment: Thanks for comment! I added a function that i used to get size of memory, and i will upload whole code soon.

Comment: please make that a [mcve]

Comment: This still doesn't show how you ran the benchmark

Comment: Sorry i'm late. i uploaded my code to https://repl.it/repls/WanEsteemedLines. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Incrementally appending to a list uses a different amount of memory from building a list straight from a range like what the op is currently doing. If you plot the memory usage from incrementallly appending to the list you will get the small steps. Just tried it.

Comment: @lightalchemist I did the same job with not fixed size but incrementally appending as you said, then i got a following result > https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vSuJ.png
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPython sets and dicts always use a power-of-two-sized internal hash table. `list`, `tuple`, and `numpy.ndarray` all have more flexibility regarding the size of their underlying memory buffer, but `set` and `dict` are hardcoded to use power-of-two table sizes. The implementation cannot function with a non-power-of-two table size. See [`Objects/dictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/dictobject.c) and [`Objects/setobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/setobject.c).

The jumps in your graph are when the table size jumps to a new power of two.

Incidentally, your `get_size` doesn't work very well. For example, it has two bugs affecting the `numpy.ndarray` case that almost cancel out (but don't quite). It tries to add the sizes of the elements of a NumPy array to the size of the whole array, but for a NumPy array, the sizes of the elements are already accounted for by `getsizeof`. Also, it's determining object identity with `id`, but the objects produced by iterating over a NumPy array are created on the fly and die immediately, so their `id` values aren't unique. In practice, this probably overcounts the size by one or two times the size of the objects representing array elements.